# While loop until there is no error

Tags: r

I would like to run a piece of code that sometimes produces an error.

For example:

```
a<-matrix(NA,ncol=1,nrow=sample(1:5,1))
a[sample(1:5,1),1]<-10
```

I would like to repeate these commands until they run without an error.

Is it possible to embed it into a while() loop that continues running until there is an error and stops when the two lines could be executed without error?

Comment: Could you not use `a[sample(1:nrow(a), 1), ] <- 10` for the second line?  That will assign 10 to a random existing position

Comment: Yes the example is an illustration of the general problem I'm facing. I wrote this code deliberately to show a situation where a code sometimes leads to error and sometimes runs without error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax for `tryCatch` looks something like

```
result = tryCatch({
    expr
}, warning = function(warning-condition) {
    warning-handler-code
}, error = function(error-condition) {
    error-handler-code
}, finally={
    cleanup-code
})
```

You can enclose your code within an infinite loop inside `tryCatch` as

```
while(1==1)
```

These 2 concepts should help you solve your problem. Using these, you could write it as

```
boolFalse<-F
while(boolFalse==F)
{
  tryCatch({
    a<-matrix(NA,ncol=1,nrow=sample(1:5,1))
    a[sample(1:6,1),1]<-10;
    boolFalse<-T
  },error=function(e){
  },finally={})
}
```

Comment: If you're embedding this logic in a function, make sure to declare the value of `boolFalse` outside of the function.